# boldSystemFontOfSize on iOS9 is returnning SFUIDisplay-Semibold instead of SFUIDisplay-Bold

Tags: ios

I find that boldSystemFontOfSize is not returning bold font if using the new sanfranciso font. I am not sure if this is a bug or intended to do so.

```
(lldb) po [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:22]
<UICTFont: 0x7fadc58a9870> font-family: ".SFUIDisplay-Semibold"; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 22.00pt
```

If you add a UILabel from storyboard and set font as bold, you need to be careful, because the size may changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue.

The quickest fix for me was to open my xib files and replace

```
type="boldSystem"
```

with

```
type="system" weight="semibold"
```

Answer (score 0):

I post this question is to warn anyone who has same issue as mine.

It took me lot of time figuring, and it turns out to be the font family problem.

If you add a UILabel from storyboard and set font as bold, you need to be careful, because the size may changed.

It seems only this SF font has a 'semi-bold' option on interface builder.